# Nesting angular binding in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Just curious if this is something that is currently possible in Angular, or if I have to write my own directive.

I'm attempting to dynamically create input tags for each property on any object.  To accomplish this, I am inspecting the object in javascript and creating an array that contains the objects property names mapped to the corresponding input "type".

**Ex.**

```
var fields = []
for (var name in myObject) {
    if (!myObject.hasOwnProperty(name)) continue;
    fields.push({ 'name': name, 'inputType': typeToInputType(myObject[name]) });
}
$scope.fields = fields;
```

Then in my markup I go ahead and do the following:

```
    <label for="{{f.name}}" ng-repeat="f in fields">
        {{f.name}}: <input name="{{f.name}}" ng-model="myObject.{{f.name}}" type="{{f.inputType}}" />
    </label>
```

Everything works great except when we get to this attribute:

```
ng-model="myObject.{{f.name}}"
```

That is causing serious problems.  The idea behind it is that I have a

```
$scope.myObject
```

and when people type stuff into the inputs, for example the "Name" input, then it should be equivalent to:

```
$scope.myObject.Name = "I typed stuff";
```

Comment: have you tried `myObject[f.name]` ?

Comment: Can you use $index? Something like myObject[$index].name

Comment: Actually, yes myObject[f.name] does the trick!

Comment: Man, angular is cool!